# Horizontal scroll bar in IE6

Tags: internet-explorer-6

I am getting a horizontal scroll bar in IE6. Attached the path to zip folder. Download and open index.html page in IE6. Let me know how to remove the  scroll bar.
[IE6-horizontal-scroll bar](http://shivanand.in/temp/IE6-horizontal-scroll.zip)

Answer (score 1):

Its one or more bad values in **padding**s. Try replacing all "padding" with "xxx" for a moment and you'll see that the problem disappears.

You also need to study [the broken box model on IE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Explorer_box_model_bug).

**Solution:**

1. Replace all **padding: 10px** with **padding: 10px 0;**
2. Fix what does not look right (padding wise)

Comment: I have a specific css file for IE6 called skin-ie.css in which I have set all the padding to "0".

Comment: Yes I saw that. Try removing all padding declarations from your CSS files and you'll see that this is the problem. Many times you do padding: 10px; width: 100%; where you should be doing padding: 10px 0; width: 100%;

Comment: It works when I change in index.css for these selectors: container, heder, footer. When I change the same for skin-ie.css it doesn't work.

Comment: Change it globally as I showed you before to fix the bug and then redo the style to make it look as it was before.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the horizontal padding of `div#container` to zero too. You're only setting the top padding in `skin-ie.css` to zero now. Change `padding-top: 0px` in `skin-ie.css` to `padding: 0` (the `px` is unnecessary for zero).

Comment: Then you'll have to provide a better, more minimal example, because this works for the file in the zip you provided... Remove elements from the page until you find out what the culprit is... The screenshot in your reply to mike nvck breaks on something not in that zip, for example.

Answer (score 0):

tried

```
html{
width:100%;
overflow-x: hidden;
}

body{
width:100%;
overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

yet?

**EDIT:**

*This works but hides right side edge content. See the link screenshot. http://shivanand.in/temp/rightside-edges-hidden.gif – Shivanand*

Hmm, that is weird. Are you using any position: absolute DIVs with width set in pixels (not %) that are causing this to happen?

Comment: This works but hides right side edge content. See the link screenshot.
http://shivanand.in/temp/rightside-edges-hidden.gif

Comment: Yes, I did use. But wait a min, I reduced the width to 98% and the scroll bar is gone.